# Check Constraint with letters and digits

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I am trying to give a constraint to a column( varchar2(7) ) where I want to have an ID in this order Letter_Letter_Digit_Digit_Letter_Letter_Letter, so 2 letters, 2 digits, 3 letters. I've tried with something like this and several instructions :

```
ALTER TABLE vehicule 
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_nr_vehicul 
CHECK (nr_vehicul LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]');
```

When I try to give something like this 'AB00BBB' my constraint is violated. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`REGEP_LIKE()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Pattern-matching-Conditions.html#GUID-D2124F3A-C6E4-4CCA-A40E-2FFCABFD8E19) function such as

```
ALTER TABLE vehicule 
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_nr_vehicul 
CHECK ( REGEXP_LIKE (nr_vehicul,'[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}') );
```

where the digits in the curly braces represent the length for each part for substrings forming the whole string of length 7.

**Update :** If you need to insert the values with some other patterns such as `AB00BB` and `B000BBB` along with the pattern of current sample value(`AB00BBB`), then use pipe oprators such as

```
ALTER TABLE vehicule 
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_nr_vehicul 
CHECK ( REGEXP_LIKE (nr_vehicul,'[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}|[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{3}[A-Z]{3}') );
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, it works. I will ask you more :).  Any ideea if I can make somehow either this 'AB00BB' or 'B000BBB' because both of them should be valid in my example. Can it be done? And how?

Comment: you're welcome @Rowend . Then you can use `OR` operator such as `REGEXP_LIKE (nr_vehicul,'[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}') OR REGEXP_LIKE (nr_vehicul,'[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{2}') OR REGEXP_LIKE (nr_vehicul,'[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{3}[A-Z]{3}')`

Comment: Oh, thanks. Why in the second REGEXP are only 2 letters in the final? typing mistake? I am trying to understand :D

Comment: because of the sample values `AB00BBB`(2,2,3), `AB00BB`(2,2,2) and `B000BBB`(1,3,3) @Rowend . Btw, rather use pipes such as `'[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}|[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{3}[A-Z]{3}'` as being briefer.

Comment: You can also use `[A-Z]{1,3}`, however you may have to check also the total length of the string.